# Combo port microphone not detected on headset

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone

Sorry for the bad title. I'm not sure if this belongs in this area of Stack Exchange, but I wasn't sure where else to put it.

I just bought a [Dell Inspiron 15 7559](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015PYZ0J6).
At first when I bought it, it came with all of your standard bloatware and unnecessary drive partitions for McAfee and stuff. I was expecting this, so I reinstalled Windows 10 with the Windows Media Creation tool. (On a flash drive.) I downloaded the drivers with the Dell Update Utility and had that install the drivers for my system. I thought it was all registered and fine, but then I tried to voice chat.

People kept telling me that my microphone quality was worse than it usually was, and I told them it was a new laptop but I'm using the same  headset (SteelSeries Siberia 100) as always. I was previously using a splitter that would take the combo jack and split into your standard separate Mic and Audio jacks.The laptop only has a combo jack, the one with 3 plastic rings. It should work out of the box, and indeed, it did. I had tried it once before I made a fresh Windows 10 install.

So I was thinking that it must be a driver issue. The headset had no drivers, and the laptop drivers should already be installed. Just to make sure, I manually downloaded all of the audio and chipset drivers from the Dell website. My new laptop still cant see the microphone when it's plugged in, but the headset works fine. The mic doesn't show up in recording devices or anything.

My question is how can I make my microphone be seen by my computer? What are your suggestions on the issue? How can I resolve it?

Thanks for the help.

[Dell Drivers Page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/4zyk1d2/drivers)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Xavierjazz I edited my question. I think since I stated a problem, that is what I would want to fix. Oh well.